# How to use OCR to read text from image

Tags: c#, asp.net, ocr

I'm trying to use [IronOCR](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIifXF7tDA6wIVVwQrCh1Y9gWyEAAYASAAEgIIgfD_BwE) to read the text from an image. I manually download their dll and include in my project and follow the example that they provided on their website. However, there is no text return at all. Even I'm trying on different file or their sample image also no result. Is there any step that I'm missing?

[image]

Here I attach the image that i'm using to try:[myImage](https://postimg.cc/QFDcmQvd)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. What is your sample image? Have try configuring other properties of the ocr like `ColorSpace`,`Strategy` etc. ?

Comment: @tontonsevilla my sample is a png file..and yes, I have tried on configuring other properties too, but still no result return.

Comment: the sample image you have is also working with me. I think there is something with the dll you downloaded. Instead of the dll download, have you tried adding IronOCR via nugetpackage?

Comment: @tontonsevilla because of some problem.. I'm not able to add via nugetpackage.. thats why I manually include in my project..

Comment: @tontonsevilla may I know where u get your dll?

Comment: at first i'm i get it via nuget, then i tried it now to manually download the dll and it still works. Just downloaded the dll from the IronOCR link in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code with the latest version of IronOCR (currently 2021.2.1) which was updated to use Tesseract 4 & 5. Returned a perfect result on your example image.

```
        var Ocr = new IronTesseract();
        using (var Input = new OcrInput(@"F:\input_image.png"))
        {
            Input.Deskew();
            var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
        }
```

Deskew filter gave the best results but there are other that may be useful listed here:
https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/examples/ocr-image-filters-for-net-tesseract/

Comment: Confirmed, working still in October 2021 version of IronOCR:  https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronOcr/2021.9.0